# What is the efficient way of reading and processing very large CSV file in scala (> 1GB)?

Tags: json, xml, scala, csv

In Scala how do you efficiently (memory consumption + performance) read very large csv file? is it fast enough to just stream it line by line and process each line at each iteration?

**What i need to do with CSV data :->**
In my application Single line in CSV file is treated as an one single record and all the records of the CSV file are to be converted into XML elements and JSON format and save it into another file in xml and json formats.

So here question is while reading the file from csv is it a good idea to read the file in chunks and provide that chunk to another thread which will convert that CSV records into an xml/json and write that xml/json to file? If yes how?

Data of the CSV can be anything, there is no restriction on the type of the data it can be numeric, big decimal, string or date. Any easy way to handle this different data types before saving it to xml? or we don't need to take care of types?

Many Thanks

Comment: the title of your question has nothing to do with the question itself, so what its actually you problem?

Comment: ok let me make it more clear in edits

Comment: Assuming the transformations don't take much time (and from your description, they don't). the time will be utterly dominated by the file I/O.  So it's going to depend on how you do that. Assuming you use some buffered read and write, it's really not going to make any difference how you structure the rest (you could use async write to allow you to process a buffer's worth while waiting for the write to complete, but that saves you only one buffer-sized-conversion time overall.

Comment: Also, 1Gb is not large. it fits in memory of most computers. so you can probably read it all in, process it all into in-memory JSON and XML and write it out as two single writes, one per output type. You could overlap those, maybe.

Comment: OK got it. Other point is my CSV there could be any type of data like there could be double quotes, single quotes, commas in the text, numbers, decimals. how will i handle all these cases?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a one time task, create a program that will break this 1GB file to small size files. Then provide those new files as a input to separate futures.
Each future will read one file and resolve in the order of file content. File4 resolves after File3, which resolves after File2, which resolves after File1.
As the file has no key-value pair or hierarchical data structure, so I will suggest, just read as a string.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are using Futures for processing of smaller chunks, how would you have control over the ordering?

Comment: you can have future oncomplete { now call the another future here to read the next file, in side that again you can do OnComplete.
Or you add all futures to a List[Future] and then call future.sequence.